# Django REST error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'BoundField'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**I have a function which outputs Friday by taking in week number as a parameter**

```
def fridayOfWeek(p_week):
    p_year=2021
    monday = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'{p_year}-W{int(p_week )- 1}-1', "%Y-W%W-%w").date()
    wednesday = monday + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
    friday  = monday + datetime.timedelta(days=6.9) - datetime.timedelta(days=2)
    return friday
```

**but when I serializer data and Set**

```
serialize = ExamSimulatorSerializer(request.data)
date = fridayOfWeek(serializer["week"])
```

it gives me an error

```
   
      File "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\backend\data_manager\views.py", line 43, in examSimulator
        date = fridayOfWeek(m['week'])
      File "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\backend\week_into_date.py", line 10, in fridayOfWeek
        monday = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'{p_year}-W{int(p_week )- 1}-1', "%Y-W%W-%w").date()
    
    Exception Type: TypeError at /api/exam-simulator/
    Exception Value: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'BoundField'
```

my serializer class is:

```
class ExamSimulatorSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    week = serializers.IntegerField() 
    subject = serializers.CharField()
    code = serializers.CharField()
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass
```

my views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@parser_classes([JSONParser])
def examSimulator(request):
    m = ExamSimulatorSerializer(request.data)
    code = m['code']
    date = fridayOfWeek(m['week'])
    subject = Subject.objects.get(name = m['subject'])
    for s in subject.students.all().values():
        student = Student.objects.get(roll_num=s['roll_num'])
        score = random.randint(25,95)
        Exam.objects.create(code=code, date=date, student=student, subject=subject,score=score)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Moreover Is this the right way to make a model-less serializer class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will be able to access the serializer data inside `serializer.data["week"]` instead of `serializer["week"]`

also note you have a small typo on the serializer variable, try this:

```
serializer = ExamSimulatorSerializer(request.data)
date = fridayOfWeek(serializer.data["week"])
```

or even:

```
serializer = ExamSimulatorSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
date = fridayOfWeek(serializer.validated_data["week"])
```

if you want to validate your data and raise an exception in case the serializer is not valid